# How to map a new automation rule in Microsoft Sentinel to a specific analytic rule using powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-sentinel

I have to create a new automation rule that will be triggered by a specific analytic rule using a powershell script.

when I execute this cmd into the script

```
New-AzSentinelAutomationRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameSentinel -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -Action $automationRuleAction -TriggeringLogicIsEnabled -DisplayName "AutomationRuleTest"
```

it creates a new automated rule for all the analytic rule which is not my case and when I try to add a parameter to allow me to choose the analytic rule name it fails

Did anyone of you could help me to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this might not be possible using PowerShell. However, you can navigate to azure portal and add the required analytical rules from there as mentioned below.

[image]

[image]